# looping on mongoDB field not sequence

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to insert data dummy until 500 in mongoDB but on my DB field not sequence

```
let saving = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          for(let i=0; i<500; i++){
            let newEmployee = new Employee({
              employee: `${i+1}`
            })
            newEmployee.save((err)=>{
              if(err) reject()
            })
          }
          resolve({message:"adding"})
      })

      saving.then((message)=>{
        res.send(message)
      })
```

and result on database like this

```
    {
     "employee" : "1",
    },
    /* 2 createdAt:7/27/2017, 9:30:39 AM*/
    {        
     "employee" : "2"
    },
    /* 3 createdAt:7/27/2017, 9:30:39 AM*/
    {
     "employee" : "4",
    },
     /* 4 createdAt:7/27/2017, 9:30:39 AM*/
    {
     "employee" : "5",
    },
    /* 5 createdAt:7/27/2017, 9:30:39 AM*/
    {
     "employee" : "3",
    },
```

how to making field database sequence?

Comment: Use [`.insertMany()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany). No need to loop ``Employee.insertMany(Array.apply([],new Array(500)).map( (n,i) => ({  "employee": `${i+1}` })),(err,results) => { ...  })``. The other part is just a common JavaScript trick of [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in order to use the "index" value in creating a array of objects at a predefined length.

Comment: thank very much @NeilLunn

Comment: The basic reason for the fail in your code is that you are not actually "awaiting" the resolution of the async callbacks to `.save()` when looping, so these basically resolve in "any sequence" and would overflow the call stack in many cases. Basic question is duplicated many times, but the cleaner solution to **your** problem is simply not to "loop" the async methods at all.